# How to insert Tradingview widget into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

I am trying to insert the following script into react render:
https://www.tradingview.com/widget/symbol-overview/

I've tried the other solutions I can find by appending script child to an id, but nothing worked.

Comment: This question has been answered [Insert tradingview widget into react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845011/how-to-to-insert-tradingview-widget-into-react-js-which-is-in-script-tag-link-h)

Comment: I have tried that method. It works for that widget, but doesn't work for the widget I am trying to use.